# ffmpeg Produces unplayable MP4 File From avi files

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, mp4, codec, avi

A have a hand full of `.avi` files which I would like to convert to `.mp4`. Cobbling together everything I have found on the Internet, I end up with something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i something.avi -c:v copy -c:a copy something.mp4
```

What I get is playable on VLC player, but, of course, that will play anything I through at it. However, I cannot play it using QuickLook in the Finder or with the QuickTime player.

In some cases I get video, but no sound. In some other cases I get garbled video.

I am guessing that the audio or video codec inside the `.avi` file is incompatible with MacOS, and that the `copy` instruction above is not appropriate. In that case I guess that I would actually need to reencode the audio or video.

If this sounds incoherent, I admit I know very little about video files.

What would be the best settings to try to produce an MP4 which works natively on MacOS?

Comment: https://ottverse.com/ffmpeg-convert-avi-to-mp4-lossless/

Comment: Copy and paste all of the text from the ffmpeg log. Without that info we can't provide an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *"What would be the best settings to try to produce an MP4 which works natively on MacOS?"*

Check this [useful guide](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264). 
You can try the below command as a starting point (*audio track will / should be auto-detected & converted*):

```
ffmpeg -i something.avi -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -pix_fmt yuv420p something.mp4
```

Comment: Sorry I haven’t got back on this one. I’m still putting it to the test. I did find that the resulting files were about 2/3 the size of the original. Using the link you supplied, I’m trying this: `-crf 18`, which gives me about the same size as the original. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: I was trying to convert an old avi to mp4 and it just does not play. This `pix_fmt yuv420p` solves my problem. Thx!